# How to regain access to Google Cloud Storage project (Deleted all IAM users)

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I managed to remove myself from the IAM list of a project. I thought that as the owner of the organisation, I would be able to add myself or other users back to the project.

However it seems like the project now exists without anybody being able to manage it. That seems a bit strange, as it would potentially live as a ghost project that no one can use in any way.

Does anyone know if there is a super admin user of any kind? I thought I *was* some sort of admin as I created the whole Google Cloud account and organisation, but apparently not ...

Comment: Probably you'll need to reach to the GCP Support team at https://cloud.google.com/support/ to ask for help there...

Comment: Are you still able to access to the project? or what is the current status of the project?

Comment: I can see the project in the list of projects, but i cannot do anything when i go to the project.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot when you go to the project? Or I suggest you can also go to the Issue Tracker to create an issue over there at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues to ask for help